# Linux kernel 3.x - Understand the way to get mac address in kernel space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, mac-address

#### Context

Hacking the kernel: writing a full network stack.
The LDD3 book is opened but not that helping after all.

The whole userspace stack code is there already.

Now, I want to up my network driver. But before, I need to understand simple things, for my knowledge.
I read the original driver for my card, obviously, and get no answer.

Custom kernel 3.18.x

x86_64

**I don't want to only know how use the functions but understand the intrinsics as well.**

#### Question

I dig into the kernel meanderings and am not sure how the device_register function can grab the MAC address of a NIC.

In the function

```
int device_register(struct device *dev)
```

**When have the mac been added ?**
Is it already allocated or will it be in device_add function ? So many indirections there..

How the kernel knows the mac address at the first place ? At boot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

device tree is my answer. Set at boot time.

As I understood, the mac address is read in the ram where the motherboard gathers all the connected devices. Then the kernel reads that memory region according to the different offset that the motherboard set and retrieve the information it needs.

It appears in the /sys section as it seems.

Pfeww.. Now I can keep going :)

Comment: Please try to provide a bit more details in your answer for future visitors. Then accept your own answer and reap rewards :)